# how to use captive portal to authenticate getting IP address from external DHCP?

Tags: networking, dhcp, authentication, pfsense, captive-portal

I want to force users to authenticate in a captive portal in order to get an IP address.

If that is impossible how can I give them an IP to communicate with a captive portal after authentication?

I use for pfsense for the captive portal and windows server 2012 r2 for DHCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of a captive portal network is that you have a network set up to, by default, pretty much block all traffic but DHCP and DNS, and redirect all HTTP traffic to a special web page on a local web server that contains a form that lets you authenticate. Whatever CGI or whatnot on the web server that handles that authentication form then tells the network to stop blocking/redirecting the traffic for the client (MAC address and/or IP address) that just authenticated.

To load that web page, the client must already have an IP address.

If you want clients to authenticate before they get an IP address, you can't use captive portal. You probably have to do WPA2-Enterprise (802.1X), assuming you don't want everyone to share a single passphrase for the whole network.